# The limit of spectral radius of a sequence of anti-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $D_n$ be an anti-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix such that all diagonal entries are $0$; the entries over diagonal are $1$ and thus any other entry is $-1$.

Denote $\rho_n$ be the spectral radius of $D_n$, i.e. the maximum absolute value of the eigenvalues of $D_n$.

It is known that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \rho_n / n = 2/\pi$, but I don't know how to prove it.

What I know now is that the characteristic polynomial of $D_n$ is
$$ \frac{ (\lambda + 1)^n + (\lambda -1)^n}2$$

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured it out. Note that the eigenvalues of $D_n$ are imaginary, because $D_n$ is anti-symmetric.

Let $\lambda = i \rho $ be an eigenvalue, where $\rho$ is a real number, then $|\lambda - 1| = |\lambda + 1| = r$.
Let $\lambda + 1 = r (\cos \alpha  + i \sin \alpha ) = r e^{i\alpha}$, where $|\alpha| < \pi /2$, then $\lambda - 1 = r(- \cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha) = r e^{i(\pi - \alpha) }$.

We have $e^{ni \alpha} + e^{ni (\pi - \alpha)} = 0 $, which holds if and only if $n\alpha = n (\pi - \alpha) + (2k + 1) \pi$ for some integer $k$, i.e. $\alpha = \frac{(n + 2k + 1)\pi}{2n}$.

So, $\max \alpha = (\frac12 - \frac1{2n})\pi$, and $\rho_n = \max \rho = \cot {(\frac12 - \frac1{2n})\pi}$.
$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \rho_n / n = 2/ \pi.$$